# Parse CSV and decode base64

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, parsing, base64

The goal of this script is supposed to be to find any base64 encoded strings within a particular row of a CSV, grab only the base64, add the correct amount of padding charcters to it, decode it, and write it to an output.

```cs
function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Sindows.Forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.Filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.Filename
}

$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\My Documents\"
$inputdata = Import-Csv $inputfile
$output = "C:\My Documents\output.csv"

$regex = [regex]::New('(?<=-[Ee]ncoded[Cc]ommand\s"??)[\w\d=\/!]{0,792}')

$csv1 = $inputdata | select -ExpandProperty 'NameOfRow' | ? {$_ -ne ""} 
| Select-String -Pattern $regex -Allmatches | % {$_.Matches} 
| ? {$_.Value -ne ""} | % {$_.Value}  

foreach ($line in $csv1) {
    $csvL = $line.Length
    $csvM = $csvL %= 4
    if ($csvM | % {$_ -eq 1}) {
        $line | % {$_ + "==="}
    } elseif ($csvM | % {$_ -eq 2}) {
        $line | % {$_ + "=="}
    } elseif ($csvM | % {$_ -eq 3}) {
        $line | % {$_ + "="}
    }
    $decode = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($line))
    $decode > $output
}
```

Comment: What does the `csv` look like?  Your example looks grossly over-engineered.

Comment: please post a test example of the csv

Comment: The pipeline `$csv1 = ...` is broken. If you want to wrap a pipeline and put the pipe at the beginning of the next line you must escape the preceding newline with a backtick. It's better to just have the continuing line end with the pipe, because then PowerShell automatically detects that the line is being continued. Does something else about the code you posted not work the way you expected? Are you getting errors? If so, what do they say?

Comment: The only errors I'm getting currently pertain to the decoding portion. 

'Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
At line:44 char:1
+ $decode = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException'

Some strings it works, others it gives me this error.